# SQL: Searching X table and returning rows from Y based on X data

Tags: mysql, sql

1. Search `goals` for rows where userid = 1.
2. Using returned rows, search `checkin` where `biometricid`'s match, along with the `userid`, and filter out rows that are older than the goal date.

*Note: Both the userid and biometricid are foreign tables.*

How may I do this with one query?

```
checkin
id  | userid    | date                  | biometricid   | value
1   | 1         | 2015-01-10 00:00:00   | 1             | 9
2   | 1         | 2000-05-11 00:00:00   | 1             | 7
3   | 2         | 2015-01-10 00:00:00   | 1             | 9
4   | 1         | 2015-01-10 00:00:00   | 2             | 1
5   | 1         | 2017-01-11 00:00:00   | 1             | 4

goals
id  | userid | date                 | biometricid   | value 
1   | 1      | 2000-01-05 00:00:00  | 1             | 3
2   | 1      | 2015-01-01 00:00:00  | 2             | 2
3   | 2      | 2015-01-01 00:00:00  | 1             | 2

desired result
id  | date                  | biometricid   | value 
1   | 2015-01-10 00:00:00   | 1             | 9
2   | 2017-01-11 00:00:00   | 1             | 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way you worded the question, and the fact that it seems many other questions I've answer recently used them, I was tempted to show a subselect in a WHERE; but I realize your question can be answered much more simply:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM goals AS g 
   INNER JOIN checkin AS c ON g.userid = c.userid 
      AND g.biometricid = c.biometricid
      AND c.`date` >= g.`date`
WHERE g.user_id = 1
;
```